# Error using htseq-count: Could not retrieve index file

Tags: rna-seq, sam, errors, featurecounts

I have a total RNAseq dataset that I aligned using STAR producing BAM files (sorted by coordinates). I am now trying to get counts for the lncRNA sequences using htseq-count, with the command:

```
htseq-count -m intersection-nonempty -f bam -i gene_id -r pos -s reverse ./OVCA429_Aligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam ./GRCh38_latest_genomic.gtf > ./OVCA429.counts.txt
```

This is the output:

```
[E::idx_find_and_load] Could not retrieve index file for './OVCA429_587680_1_1.rnaseq.fastqAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam'
100000 GFF lines processed.
200000 GFF lines processed.
300000 GFF lines processed.
400000 GFF lines processed.
...(truncated output here)...
3775001 GFF lines processed.
[E::idx_find_and_load] Could not retrieve index file for './OVCA429_587680_1_1.rnaseq.fastqAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam'
100000 alignment records processed.
200000 alignment records processed.
300000 alignment records processed.
...(truncated output here)...

Output text file:
__no_feature    20368875
__ambiguous 0
__too_low_aQual 0
__not_aligned   0
__alignment_not_unique  2634439
```

I've read through the htseq-count literature but it never asks to include an index file, therefore i'm not sure how to deal with this problem. Any help/ suggestions would be welcome! Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be missing index files of the bam files (therefore the error message that the index file is missing). You should be able to generate those with `samtools`, e.g.

```
samtools index ./OVCA429_587680_1_1.rnaseq.fastqAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam
```

Comment: As it happens I did have the index file as well, I just ended up naming it differently and so the application probably didn't recognise it. Once I changed the name to match the bam file, it worked out perfectly file. Nevertheless, thank you for your help! :)

Comment: Ah, I did not even think this could be a problem as samtools do not give you an option to give it a different name. GLad you resolved it!

Comment: I have created the index using what Kamil suggested but I am not able to generate the counts file. This is what I use: `for i in *fastqAligned.sortedByCoord.out.bam; do htseq-count -r pos -f bam $i /gpfs/scratch/mice/GCA-000001635.90-GRCm39-genomic.gtf > $i_output_basename.counts ; done`

Comment: @christosnoutsos 1. that was not an answer. You should open a new question, link this one and explain why the solution did not work for you. 2. I would put quotation marks around `$i` in `$i_output_basename.counts`, i.e. `"$i"_output_basename.counts`. You probably created a bunch of files `.count` that replaced each other.